# How to retrieve updated/changed data from parse.com (android)?

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                            ParseConstants.CLASS_POSTS);
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> posts, ParseException e) {

                            if (e == null) {
                                // we found posts
                                mPosts = posts;


                                ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(mPosts);
```

I have retrieved posts and saved on parse localDatastore by code shown above.
and later I have used `ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(ParseConstants.CLASS_POSTS);
        query.fromLocalDatastore();`
to get posts locally.

But by pinAllInBackground method whole copy of posts get downloaded and saved in localstore. I just want to pin new posts. which method I should call?

Comment: I do not want to download all data every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution.
to retrieve only new data we should compare createdAt by adding this to query.

```
query.whereGreaterthanOrEqualTo("createdAt",dateOfLastRetrievedObject);
```